# Can not Pull/Clone GitLab Existing Repository - Able to connect via both SSH and HTTP

Tags: git, clone, gitlab, pull

I have a account on http://gitlab.com. I have some private projects there. I am able to connect to projects using SSH and HTTP from command line/git bash.

When I try to do a Pull/Clone it connects and starts download successfully. It shows me the no of files, compression and download progress too.

However, even after download is completed, there are NO files/folders created locally in the destination folder.

This is happening for 2 projects however not for the third one. I haven't set any specific permissions/configurations for any project. I have tried this from multiple windows boxes.

At no point do I get any errors about connection or permissions.

Any suggestions for debugging this problem would be much appreciated.